# Adding conditional fields to Slash command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

how can I add some fields that will show if the user chooses an option from discord.Option() list?
I mean if user chooses 'Option a1' he/she will see field 'a1' and if he chooses 'Option b2' he/she will see field 'a2'.
this is my code for option list:

```py
@warn_command_group.command(name='remove',description='حذف اخطار')
    async def remove_warn(self, ctx:discord.ApplicationContext,
                          mode:discord.Option(str,'حالت حذف',choices=[
                              'حذف کل اخطار های سرور', # delete all warns
                              'حذف کل اخطار های یک ممبر', # delete all warns from a member
                              'حذف یک اخظار خاص(با استفاده از آیدی اون اخطار)' # delete a specific warn (with that warn's id)
                          ])
                          ):
```

I mean if they choose the first option, they will not see any forced field
if they choose the second option, they will see a field named "member" with the type of discord.Member
and if they choose the third option, they'll see a field named "id" with the type of int

Comment: AFAIK this is not supported by Discord, so you can't do this as of right now

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not indent the function after the decorator.
Then, To create choices for your `mode` parameter, you can use the arg `choices` as you did, which is a `list`.

In this list, there should be `discord.OptionChoice()` classes in it.

In your case, you will get:

```
@warn_command_group.command(name='remove',description='حذف اخطار')
async def remove_warn(self, ctx:discord.ApplicationContext,
                      mode:discord.Option(str,'حالت حذف', required=True, choices=[
                          discord.OptionChoice(name='حذف کل اخطار های سرور', value="deleteAll"),
                          discord.OptionChoice(name='حذف کل اخطار های یک ممبر', value="deleteMemberAll"),
                          discord.OptionChoice(name='حذف یک اخظار خاص(با استفاده از آیدی اون اخطار)', value="deleteWarn")
                      ])
                      ):

   if mode == "deleteAll":
         #Some stuff if the user has selected the first choice

   elif mode == "deleteMemberAll":
        #Some stuff is the user has selected the second choice
   
   else:
        #Some stuff is the user has selected the third choice
```

See https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=discord%20option#discord.Option.choices