# Slash command autocompletion in pycord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

I want to start working with SlashCommand autocompletion in pycord. Since I think that my request in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73415958/adding-conditional-fields-to-slash-command) is impossible, I thought to myself that maybe I can change the autocomplete based on the user's choice in one of the slash-command entries and display the desired entry to the user earlier.
I'm asking this because I don't found any good resource for learning this and I don't  understand docs

Answer (score 0):

there is an example from the Pycord documents, I think if you experiment with this part of the code, you will understand how it can work

> https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/blob/master/examples/app_commands/slash_autocomplete.py

If you want use them in cogs
there's my part for cogs

```
import discord
from discord import option
from discord.ext import commands

mycolors = ["red", "white", "yellow"]


class ExampleAutocompletion(commands.Cog):
    ctx_parse = discord.ApplicationContext

    def __init__(self, bot: discord.Bot):
        self.bot = bot.user

    @staticmethod
    def colorAutocomplete(self: discord.AutocompleteContext):
        return mycolors

    @staticmethod
    def flowertypeAutocomplete(self: discord.AutocompleteContext):
        chosen_color = self.options["color"]
        match chosen_color:
            case "red":
                return ["Rose", "Georgina"]
            case "white":
                return ["Chrisantem", "Gortensia"]
            case "yellow":
                return ["Sunflower", "Narciss"]
            case _:
                return ["There is no flower with this color"]

    @commands.slash_command(
        guild_ids=["Your Guild ID for test"],
        description="")
    @option("color", description="What's your favourite color?",
            autocomplete=colorAutocomplete)
    @option("flowertype", description="and that's your flower shape!",
            autocomplete=flowertypeAutocomplete)
    async def beautyflowers(self, ctx: ctx_parse,
                            color: str, flowertype: str):
        await ctx.respond(f"My flower is {flowertype} and its color is {color}!")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(ExampleAutocompletion(bot))
```